# django reverse to multiple page id

Tags: python, django

I use the same modal forms in different pages to fill some database entry.
My problem is I don't know how to use "reverse" so it bring me back to the right page on success.

views.py:

```
class StorageLocationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalCreateView):
template_name = 'inventory/storagelocation_create_form.html'
form_class = StorageLocationModalForm
success_message = 'Success: storage Location was created.'
success_url = reverse_lazy("page1")
```

Here my code can only send back to *page1* weather i'm calling the modal from *page1* or *page2*.

How can reverse to the good page dynamically ?

Comment: Hello sir, django doesn't know what page that the request is comming from, you can add another variable in request and check which page this request is comming from or you can do this in template using ajax (js)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using HTTP_REFFER.

Override get_success_url() with something like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        previous_url = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return previous_url
```

Some more info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META).